# Compare value of a cell in a column and indicates if exists in the column or not

Tags: excel, report, formula, vlookup

I have two excel columns. I want to take every cell in E and compare the value to all of D column and indicate if that cell of E exists in D column
how can I do that?

I use VLOOKUP and I want the locations of cells which E matches D

```
=VLOOKUP(E3,D3:E21,1,FALSE)
```

[This IMAGE is how my data would look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cwoe.png)

Answer (score 1):

In column F write something like `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E1,D:D,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(E1,D:D,1,0))` or `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E1,D:D,1,0)),"","Matches")` depending on what you want it to say when it matches.

If there is no match it will leave it with no text in the cell.